# Шаблоны JavaScript-Templates не хотят работать с Django

Tags: javascript, django

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь заставить работать [jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) с django, однако не получается. Вот эта строка:

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
Exception Value:
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {
```

Как я понял, библиотека [JavaScript-Templates](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/) конфликтует со стандартными шаблонами django. Как бы это исправить, чтобы не переделывать?

Подумалось, может быть, есть способ, чтобы пометить участок таким образом, чтобы django его не обрабатывал, например, вынести в отдельный файл и включить спец. директивой как текст.
Подскажите возможные способы заставить заработать эту jQueryFileUpload на django.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тэгом [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim).

Содержимое тэга не будет обработано шаблонизатором django, что позволит избежать коллизий:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
{% endverbatim %}
```